# Is there any 3D-printing software that supports Raspberry Pi?

Tags: software, raspberry-pi

My only functional computer at the moment is a raspberry pi, and I was wondering if there was any software that supported it. My printer is a Newmatter mod-t, but I might be able to modify other software to support it

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system?

Comment: Also, what version of the Raspberry Pi do you have and how much memory does it have?

Comment: Also, what kind of software are you looking for. Your printer seems to have a built-in slicer and can be operated from a web browser. Are you looking for design software?

Comment: One thing worth remembering is TinkerCad runs entirely in the web browser; if you can open a web site, you can do basic 3d modeling.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn tinkercad needs webGL, which is not 100% supported by every browser and platform, while HTML is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "yes", but it depends on what hardware you have, what operating system you are using, and what software you want (or need) to use.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with 4GB of memory, and I am running a 32-bit version of Raspberry Pi OS. I have been able to install the following software from the Raspberry Pi OS repositories, but not everything is working "out of the box":

- Blender 2.79 (starts, but not tested)
- Cura 3.3.1 (crashes on startup)
- FreeCAD 0.18 (crashes when opening a new document)
- PrintRun (PronterFace) 1.6.0 (working)
- PrusaSlicer (Slic3r PE) 1.39.2 (working)
- Repetier-Host 0.85 (crashes on startup)
- Slic3r 1.3.0 (working)

I have been able to download the 3DBenchy from Thingiverse, slice it using Slic3r, and PrintRun (PronterFace) is currently printing it on my Tronxy X1.

I will update this answer if I can get the other stuff working, since I would quite like to use a Raspberry Pi for 3D design and printing. If I can get FreeCAD working, I shall be happy, and OpenSCAD would be a welcome bonus, but I don't think that it has been ported.

Comment: Blender is a very powerful tool with a reputation to be horrible to use for newbies, but its UI gets better and better. However, UI changes between editions can be huge...

Comment: @Trish Understood. I'm not really interested in Blender for my own use (at least, not yet), but I will try to produce a simple STL file with it if I can. I expect that it has been pretty well tested on the RPi, so it should work.

Comment: Cura 3.3 is ancient and would not be a good idea even if it worked. You need to just get latest from source and build it yourself. I don't see any good reason it shouldn't run on arm, so I'd expect it to work fine. (In fact, I'm pretty sure lots of ppl already run at least the CuraEngine backend on arm/rpi through OctoPrint or other print managers - don't they let you do slicing in the pring manager?)

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of [Atwood's Law](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-principle-of-least-power/).

Remember that [TinkerCAD](https://www.tinkercad.com/) runs entirely in your web browser. If your Raspberri Pi can browse the web, you can do basic 3D modeling.

Similarly, there is an online slicer available at [cnc-apps.com](https://cnc-apps.com/en/app/stl2gcode) — probably others, too. If you can browse the web, you can slice an STL to create gcode suitable for most printers. It's free to use (with limits) for guests. However, I haven't used it personally so I can't speak to the quality at this time. (If anyone wants to try this out, I'd love to hear your results).

The final step is getting the printer to run the generated g-code, and here we have our old friend [OctoPrint](https://octoprint.org/download/). I'm currently running this on a Raspberry Pi of my own. However, I'd be hesitant to give the Pi over to running the printer if it's your only computer. In most cases I would instead copy the gcode file to an sd card, but as the particular printer here it seems to support wifi it's likely you can upload the gcode directly.

Comment: Octoprint can't detect my printer

Comment: I mentioned two other options for you to look at.